# Moving primary key from int to Guid

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, guid

In my current project, I have to sync multiple client databases to one server database. I had given a try with Microsoft's sync framework and is not useful in my case. Therefor I have to do sync manually. for that I need to change **primary key constraints** from **int** to **guid** in all the tables.

Problem is this primary keys are also referred as foreign key in other tables.
I had referred below,

[Moving from ints to GUIDs as primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138177/moving-from-ints-to-guids-as-primary-keys)

I am not good at **SQL**. I understood the logic but actual implementation is very tough for me.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD GuidCol NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT AK_GuidCol UNIQUE(GuidCol)
```

in above code I tried to add a column GuidCol as unique column after googling a lot. But
**I don't know How can I fill values in the newly created column?**
**How can I make this column as PK after assigning value(s)?**
**How to make sure that this process won't break existing foreign key constraints?**

Comment: What would a manual sync have to do with the type of the foreign keys?  You may be trying to address the wrong issue.

Comment: There is no use of foreign keys in manual sync. But here I'm trying add new unique GUID column. I want this column to be PK so for that I need to update all the foreign key tables. For example. if PK is 1 , Guid is G then I need to change the entry in other table where FK is 1 to G. Sorry for bad write up. I hope you'll get what I want to say.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving from ints to GUIDs as primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138177/moving-from-ints-to-guids-as-primary-keys)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know How can I fill values in the newly created column?

The link you provided gives a solution:

> Create a new column for the guid value in the master table. Use the
>   **uniqueidentifier** data type, **make it not null with a newid()
>   default** so all existing rows will be populated.

So your code should look like this:

```
alter table myTable add GuidCol uniqueidentifier not null default newid()
```

> How can I make this column as PK after assigning value(s)? How to
>   make sure that this process won't break existing foreign key
>   constraints?

The same answer tells you:

- Create new uniqueidentifier columns in the child tables.
- Run update statements to build the guild relationships using the
  exisitng int relationships to reference the entities.
- Drop the original int columns.

Use the same `uniqueidentifier` type as in previuos statement, but instead of providing `defalut`, run the update statements joining the tables on existing integer `id` and set in the child's column the corresponding parent value.
Now you have child-parent relationship established but without constraints on them. Drop `int` columns and create PK and FK on new `guid` columns